# Problem with Django query on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've met a problem with my Django query. So, I have a filter like this.

```
Discount.objects.filter(end_date__gte=date.today()) #end_date is DateField
```

It works properly on my localhost. But, on the server that I deployed with Elastic Beanstalk, it still returns yesterday's records. And, when I redeploy the server (without any changes), it works fine, yesterday's records have been filtered and hided.

I tried but can't find where is the problem. Hope anyone can help me.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django often times will handle timezones on the view for you, but within the backend you can run into time discrepancies with the server time vs local time to your user(the view)

One thing that can help is to setup your django timezone settings.py:

```
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
    USE_TZ = True
```

If you are still running into issues of local-time not matching server time you can do some translations to the time.

```
    from django.utils import timezone
    to_tz = timezone.get_default_timezone()
    import datetime
    
    Discount.objects.filter(end_date__gte=datetime.datetime.today().astimezone(to_tz))
```

Test in shell by running: python manage.py shell

```
    from django.utils import timezone
    from app.models import Discount
    to_tz = timezone.get_default_timezone()
    import datetime
    print(f"Today is: {datetime.datetime.today().astimezone(to_tz)}")
    todays_discounts = Discount.objects.filter(end_date__gte=datetime.datetime.today().astimezone(to_tz))
    for each in todays_discounts:
        print(f"{each} date:{each.end_date}")
```

Managing timezones in the template:

```
     {% load tz %}
     <!-- some html code here -->
     Date: {{ context.object.end_date|timezone:"America/La_Paz" }}
```

or

```
    {% load tz %}
    {% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Date: {{ context.object.date }}
    {% endtimezone %}
```

Comment: Thank you @noes1s for your reply. I config my project with `TIME_ZONE` and `USE_TZ` as you recommended. But I'm not sure that it works properly at run time. Let me try with your solution

Comment: So run python manage.py shell and try the code but print the results of datetime so you can see if it is matching up to your local time. I updated the answer to show an example of testing in shell.

Comment: Oh, yah, I tried Django shell before this post. It works properly. Just returning the wrong records in the api view. That's the problem :(. Btw I used Django rest framework.

Comment: Are you trying shell on the AWS instance, or are you trying shell on your local machine? Because that would be a big difference. Also, Django Views handle time formatting for timezones on their own, so if what you are seeing in the view is different from what you  are getting in shell, then you can do some time translations in the template. I'll update my answer